# error "ld terminated with signal 6" for theos project after upgrade to Xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, jailbreak

I'm using https://github.com/DHowett/theos to implement a tweak for jailbroken iphone.
I followed http://brandontreb.com/beginning-jailbroken-ios-development-getting-the-tools/ and everything worked fine.
Then I upgrade my Xcode to 4.5.
Then when compiling any tweak projects, even a hello world project, it failed with following error:

```
    Making all for tweak PreferenceLoader...
    Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
    Compiling Tweak.xm...
    Linking tweak PreferenceLoader...
    collect2: ld terminated with signal 6 [Abort trap: 6]
    ld(8724,0x7fff78fd2960) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f89b35003f0: pointer being freed was not allocated
    *** set a breakpoint in mallocerror_break to debug
    make[2]: *** [obj/PreferenceLoader.dylib] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [internal-library-all] Error 2
    make: *** [PreferenceLoader.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

I found this http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.jp/2012/06/how-to-install-thoes-under-xcode-44.html, followed all steps, but still no luck.

Any ideas on the linking tool's crash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

got feedback from https://github.com/DHowett/theos/issues/39

Xcode 4.5 ships with two different versions of the same linker. The one used by gcc (which is deprecated) crashes on armv6 output, and the one used by clang can not generate armv6 output.
There is currently no way to use the 6.0 SDK while targeting iOS versions less than 4.3, or any armv6 platforms.
If you're willing to accept this, please add the following to the top of your Makefile:

export ARCHS=armv7
export TARGET=iphone:latest:4.3

(note from theiostream)
Alternatively, it is possible to use older SDKs and build for both architectures and older deployment targets (up from 3.0). Just force them (if they exist on your Xcode Developer directory), as:

export ARCHS = armv6 armv7
export TARGET=iphone::